# NGINX multiple server_name, but have robots.txt file for each server_name?

Tags: nginx, robots.txt, server-name

I have to create a server_name as a listener for origin pulls by my CDN.

The CDN wants to pull from origin.mydomain.com

I already have 100s of lines of code under www.mydomain.com that showcases all the rewrites, rules and such, and I need to use all this code again.

My easy solution would be to have

server_name www.mydomain.com origin.mydomain.com

To easily have NGINX listen for the requests to the "origin" subdomain.

My fear is that google discovers the subdomain and starts crawling it. I'd like to block google from the "origin" subdomain somehow. Since declaring multiple server_name, I am not sure I can just place robots.txt file somewhere, since using same root folder as live site.

Is there an easy way to do this?

All feedback appreciated.

Cheers
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Use two `server` blocks and use the `include` directive to pull in the common code. For example:

```
server {
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    include /path/to/common/config;

    location = /robots.txt {
        root /path/to/friendly/dir;
    }
}
server {
    server_name origin.mydomain.com;
    include /path/to/common/config;

    location = /robots.txt {
        root /path/to/unfriendly/dir;
    }
}
```

So you have two `robot.txt` files in different directories - or use `rewrite ... last` to map the URI to different local files.

Comment: Okay, so simplify by including all the rewrites and such in an external code that can be included. does the include have to have any format? Or just cut/paste into blank config file?

Comment: [The documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) states that "Included files should consist of syntactically correct directives and blocks". Basically a cut & paste.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm getting an error.

nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/rewrite_rules.conf:7

Comment: I am now having in the main site conf `server {
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    include/usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/traileraddict_rules.conf

    location = /robots.txt {
        root /path/to/friendly/dir;
    }
}`

Comment: It's not a good idea to put the files in an existing include directory, otherwise some other `nginx` file is going to suck them in too. You will probably find that `conf.d` is already taken.

Comment: ok, I instead made the include point to `include /usr/include/rewrite_rules;` Does that work?

Comment: I changed the directory again, include /home/ to make sure no chance of OS making changes.

All in all, it worked! I tried to upvote your answer but my level isn't high enough yet.